# Very simple Angularjs code not working,

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I started out angularjs this morning. I got the right result in the morning. 
But for some reason, this very simple angularjs code doesn't work anymore.

```
<html ng-app = "jajc">
  <head>
  <title>TESTER</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="searchthis" action="/search" style="display:inline;" method="get">
<input id="ser" name="q" size="80" type="text" ng-model = "name"     placeholder="Enter a place "/>
        <input id="sub" value="Search" type="submit"/>
        <p>Welcome {{name}}</p>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about it doesn't work?

Comment: I get Welcome {{name}} on my browser.

Comment: that generally means that the application crashed along the way or failed to bootstrap or that you're missing a dependency. Also, remove spacing between ng-app and "jajc" those should be connected without spacing.

Comment: Is there any way this code would have crashed?

Comment: One thing the puzzles me is that the same code worked in the morning!

Comment: Yes, Your application code seems to be missing. You only have the angular code, but where is your app defined? Also, open your dev console and see what error you get.

Comment: Check developer tools in the browser for errors. But tit looks like a controller isn't set

Comment: Removing spacing didn't help.

Comment: Oh, I'm really sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular searches for module **Jajc** and failed to load as you havent written any code to register this module. instead just write **ng-app** in html tag and remove the name. refer below code -

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app>
<form id="searchthis" action="/search" style="display:inline;" method="get">
<input id="ser" name="q" size="80" type="text" ng-model = "name" placeholder="Enter a place "/> </input>
        <input id="sub" value="Search" type="submit"></input>
        <p>Welcome {{name}}</p>
  </form>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define a ng-controller

Answer (score 0):

It is just because you have named the app as "jajc" and you have not created any angular module with the same name.

Simply remove the "jajc" and keep your `<html>` tag as `<html ng-app>`will do the job.